# Custom routing ASP.NET MVC set default action in each controller

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to define route that it link to default action.

For example,

```
/Customer/acme-company

/Client/bill-johnson
```

Always looking for method Get in controllers Client and Customer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the parameter defaults.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",                                   // Route name
    "{controller}/{someParameter}",              // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Get" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Like my comment on [UpTheCreek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883152/custom-routing-asp-net-mvc-set-default-action-in-each-controller/5883228#5883228), this is valid as well.  However, I think that depending on the scale and how the controllers are instantiated, it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Client",
    "Client/{name}",
    new { controller = "Client", action = "Get", });
```

Comment: then the second URL won't match...the first part of the route needs to be dynamic.

Comment: In my opinion it would be better to define two routes, rather than one to fit all situations.

Comment: Fair enough - matter of opinion i guess. But it looks like he's only wanting to server 2 urls, not really "all situations".

Comment: @RPN1984 & @UpTheCreek: You just have to add the second route (the answer is incomplete without the Customer route).  Both approaches are valid, depending on the context.  If you were custom injecting controllers through DI, for example, one route to rule them all is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @casparOne - i agree. But we can only go on what the OP has asked - which is a way to handle 2 routes. We have no idea what other routes or DI configuration he has setup.